# Angularjs Params

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to post a `tag` under a BlogPost.

Here's what I started with (Angularjs Service):

```
angular.module('app.tags').factory("Tags", ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('posts/:postID/tags/:tagId', {
        tagId: '@_id',
        postID: // Post ID?
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

**How would I get the `postID` to match up with my Post's ID?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documented](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route) with `$route` service the `current.params` object holds all of the current route parameters.

```
$route.current.params
```

So, you can address `postId` by injecting `$route` and asking for:

```
$route.current.params.postId
```